# Is SQL capable of returning nested data? If not, is there a best practice for this?

Tags: sql, json, node.js, nested-lists, node-mssql

Right now I'm working with a query which outputs about 20k lines of data from table1. Node conveniently converts this to a simple JSON. So it's a huge object containing the outputted rows as smaller objects.

```
{
    { // item 1
        column1: value1,
        column2: value2,
        ...
    },
    { // item 2
        column1: value1,
        column2: value2,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

For each item in this result I'd like to select more values from table2. However, the correlation between an item in the list and the rows of table 2 is one to many. That is, if I do a simple left join, it puts out something like this:

```
{
    { // item 1 with added value from table2
        ...
    },
    { // item 1 with different value from table2
        ...
    },
    { // item 1 with yet another value from table2
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

This is incredebly wasteful on bandwith and is way above the speed limit I want it to work at for 20k rows. What I'd somehow want to achieve is a structure like this one:

```
{
    { // item 1
        column1: value1,
        column2: value2,
        ...
        {
            table2value1: value1,
            table2value2: value2,
            ...
        }
    },
    { // item 2
        column1: value1,
        column2: value2,
        ...
        {
            table2value1: value1,
            table2value2: value2,
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

For now, just looping through the 20000 items in a prepared statement is my best guess on how to do this. However, this is also quite slow, and there's probably a better way I don't know of (or couldn't think of). Some specs: working with Node, mssql package and SQL Server 2000 (so sorry) as the database.

Any input is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you want to do an LEFT JOIN on the server...

Comment: LEFT JOIN is the exactly what gives this result. Sorry for not specifying.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a query that returns an ordered list:

```
customer   order   orderline   ...
1          1       1
1          1       2
1          2       1
2          3       1
```

Client side, you can iterate over this rowset and create a new customer whenever the customer id changes, a new order when the order number changes, and so on.  The fact that this approach uses only one database call makes it pretty fast.